# Process synchronization using semaphores

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, semaphore

I want to know if my approach in the following case is correct or not:

```
There are 5 processes P1, P2, P3, P4 ad P5. And they can execute as follows:

• P1 can start any time.
• P2 can start after P1 completes.
• P3 can start after P1 completes.
• P4 can start after both P2 and P3 complete.
• P5 can start after P4 completes.

This needs to be explained using semaphores.
```

My APPROACH: P2 and P3 must wait on P1 (say semaphore S1). P4 must wait on P2 and P3 (say semaphore S2), and P5 must wait on P4 (say semaphore S3). So, initially all the other processes are waiting except P1. P1 executes and S1 blocks any other process that comes. After P1 completes execution, it can post twice, so now P2 and P3 are executing and P4 and P5 are waiting. When P2 and P3 complete, S2 can post, then P4 can execute and P5 is waiting. After P4 is complete, then S3 posts and P5 then executes.

Is this right? Also, there are a few confusions. What will be the initial values of the semaphores in each case? Is it 1 for S1, 2 for S2 and 1 for S3? Also, when P1 comes to execute, then S1 becomes 0 and blocks all the other processes, similarly for other cases, but how does it know to allow only P1 and any other process first?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve or is this a hypothetical? Have you also looked at using a thread safe FIFO Queue instead?

Comment: @Igor Could you tell me if this solution deadlocks at any point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost correct. However, in order for P4 to wait on *both* P2 and P3, it must acquire S2 twice (P2 and P3 do not need to synchronize mutually then - they both simply post once to S2.

When the processes initiate, they *all* should be waiting on a semaphore (except P1). P2 and P3 wait on S1, P4 on S2, and P5 on S3. Semaphores block when their count is zero. Ergo, initial values for all semaphores should be zero.

P1 executes immediately due to the simple reason that it does not wait on any semahore, it just starts its task.

Comment: Oh okay! I get it. Thanks!

Comment: One question though, does this solution deadlock at any point?

Comment: In simplest form, deadlock occurs when process A holds resource X, and needs resource Y to proceed. Simultaneously, process B holds resource Y and needs resource X to proceed. As there are no cross-dependencies like that in your control flow, there is no possibility of a deadlock.